# Getting The Docroot From $data in provision_apache_vhost_config With Aegir3

Tags: aegir

I'm trying to write a custom vhost hook for Aegir3 and I need to get the site's docroot path.  I can see that the info I want is being passed in the second variable ($data) but I can't figure out how to access it.  It seems like there is an object $data['server'] that is of a custom Provision_Context_server class.

Can anyone provide an example or point me at some documentation on how to interact with that?  I was hoping to be able to just use $data['server']['services']['http']['context']['site']['root'] but that doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:
I managed to get to the data as follows, but it's an ugly hack:

```
  preg_match('/"root";s:\d*:"(.*?)"/', serialize($data), $aryMatches);
  $docRoot = $aryMatches[1];
```

Comment: I've added a new section to explain this on http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/extend/altering-behaviours/#finding-what-data-is-passed-to-a-hook

Comment: Thanks Herman, but do you have an example on how to use the data?  IE, I don't want to just see the data that is getting sent, I need to use it in my hook function.  Specifically, I'm looking for some way to access the root field.  IE, would I use d($data)->root or the like?  I need to get the DocRoot path for a custom entry in my vhost, but I can't figure a way to extract it out of $data short of serializing the variable and writing a regexp to pull it out of the text.

Comment: `d()->root` would probably be what you need. The drush_log command on the page mentioned above is the best way to see what data you've actually got.